When I use mix() in dart-sass, the output is rgb() instead of HEX(#)
I use gulp@5.0.0 , gulp-sass@6.0.0 on Mac.
The gulp task are as follows.
import { src, dest, series, watch } from 'gulp';
import * as dartSass from 'sass';
import gulpSass from 'gulp-sass';

const sass = gulpSass(dartSass);

const sassTask = (done) => {
  src([ "src/sass/**/*.scss"])
    .pipe(
        sass().on('error', sass.logError)
    )
    .pipe(dest('css'))
    .on('end', done);
};

const watchTask = (done) => {
  watch("src/sass/**/*.scss", series(sassTask))
    .on('end', done);
};

export { sassTask, watchTask };

export default watchTask;


A sample is shown below.
@use "sass:color";

$color_brown: #58504c;

p {
  color: color.mix($color_brown, #fff, 50%);
}

The results are as follows.
p {
  color: rgb(104.7, 97.5, 93.9);
}

The results I want are as follows.
p {
  color: #69625e;
}

In other environments, the output is in HEX, but I encountered this situation when I was building this new environment.
Is there any configuration I need to do?

Did you try passing $method: rgb as last param when calling the mix dart-module?

@Luckyfella
Thanks for the reply.
I tried adding $method: rgb but the result didn't change.
I tried adding $method: oklch and the value changed, so it looks like the $method is working.

I found a similar description in the documentation.
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/colors/#color-functions

I found a temporary solution in the form of rolling back to sass 1.78.0 and gulp-sass 5.1.0 (not necessary)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
